# Google Maps and Yelp API mash-up doesn't work with some searchterms

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am currently working on a webapplication mashing up the Yelp and Google Maps API's. I finished the code and it seemed to be working until I found out that google maps won't show up with certain searchterms. For example when I search for Pizza in Denver my app works perfectly, but when i search for Sushi in New York, Google Maps just doesn't load. I checked my source code after doing the search and the results are all there. I can't seem to figure out what's the problem. The app is [online](http://www.frankkluytmans.nl/zoek.php)  .

The Google Maps code snippet:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      //Er word een kaart neergezet
      function initialize(lat,lon,label) {
        var lancenter =
          "<?
          echo $latitude_center
          ?>";
        var loncenter = 
          "<?
          echo $longitude_center
          ?>";
          var map;
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 12,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(lancenter, loncenter),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);

    var companyLogo = new google.maps.MarkerImage('image.png',
    new google.maps.Size(35,60),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(18,60)
    );
    var companyShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('shadow.png',
    new google.maps.Size(69,60),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(18,60)
    );




<?    
//Er word een loop gemaakt die de array met resultaten doorloopt en vervolgens markers, infowindows en beschrijving op de kaart plaatst voor alle resultaten.
     while($i<sizeof($response["businesses"])) {
        $latitude_result = $response["businesses"][$i]["location"]["coordinate"]["latitude"];
        $longitude_result = $response["businesses"][$i]["location"]["coordinate"]["longitude"];  
        $result_description = $response["businesses"][$i]["name"];
        $result_rating = $response["businesses"][$i]["rating_img_url_small"];
        $result_ratingnr = $response["businesses"][$i]["review_count"];
        $result_beschrijving = $response["businesses"][$i]["snippet_text"];
        $result_beschrijving=str_replace("\n"," ",$result_beschrijving);
        $result_beschrijving=str_replace("\r"," ",$result_beschrijving);
        $result_adres0 = $response["businesses"][$i]["location"]["display_address"][$i];
        $result_adres1 = $response["businesses"][$i]["location"]["display_address"]["1"];
        $result_adres2 = $response["businesses"][$i]["location"]["display_address"]["2"];
        $result_adres3 = $response["businesses"][$i]["location"]["display_address"]["3"];
        $result_image = $response["businesses"][$i]["image_url"];
        $result_url = $response["businesses"][$i]["url"];
        $result_image = $result_image ? $result_image : 'noimg.gif';
        $result_beschrijving = $result_beschrijving ? $result_beschrijving : 'Er is helaas geen beschrijving beschikbaar voor deze locatie.';
        ?>   



     var lanresult =
          "<?
          echo $latitude_result
          ?>";
     var lonresult = 
          "<?
          echo $longitude_result
          ?>";
    var resultloc = new google.maps.LatLng(lanresult, lonresult);
     var beschrijving = 
          '<h3>'+"<?
          echo "<div id='container'>",Naam,":","&nbsp;","<h2>", $result_description,"</h2>","</br>",Beschrijving,":","&nbsp;","<h2>", $result_beschrijving,"<a href='", $result_url,"' target='_new'>","Lees verder","</a>","</h2>","</br>", Adres,":","&nbsp;","<h2>", $result_adres0,"</br>", $result_adres1,"</h2>","</br>", Waardering,":","&nbsp;","<img src='", $result_rating,"'/>","<h2>",$result_ratingnr,"&nbsp;",recensies,"</h2>","</br>","<img src='", $result_image,"'/>","</br>","</br>","<h2>","<a href='", $result_url,"' target='_new'>","Lees meer informatie via YELP","</a>","</h2>","</div>"
          ?>";'</h3>'

                  var marker<? echo $i; ?> = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: companyLogo,
        shadow: companyShadow,
        position: resultloc,
        });
        var infowindow<? echo $i; ?>= new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: beschrijving,
        maxWidth: 260
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker<? echo $i; ?>, 'click', function() {
          infowindow<? echo $i; ?>.open(map,marker<? echo $i; ?>);
        });


    <?
        $i++;
     } // einde while php
     ?>
     }  
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

I really hope someone can help me.

Kind Regards